# How do I change the mod2 labels in interact_plot()?

Tags: r, plot, regression, interaction

I have the following interaction:

```
data(iris)
View(iris)

reg <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width*Petal.Width*Petal.Length, data = iris)
```

I want to create a plot:

```
library(interactions)

interact_plot(reg, pred = Sepal.Width, modx = Petal.Width, mod2 = Petal.Length, data = iris, x.label = "Sepal Width", y.label = "Sepal Length", legend.main = c("Petal Width"), mod2.labels = c("Petal Length"))
```

The problem is that I can't seem to change the Petal.Length variable in my plot to "Petal Length" with the `mod2.labels` function. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a vector of complete labels - one per facet:

```r
interact_plot(reg, pred = Sepal.Width, modx = Petal.Width, 
              mod2 = Petal.Length, data = iris, x.label = "Sepal Width", 
              y.label = "Sepal Length", 
              legend.main = c("Petal Width"),
              mod2.labels = c("Mean of Petal Length - 1 SD",
                              "Mean of Petal Length",
                              "Mean of Petal Length + 1 SD"))
```

[image]